# Magento 2 : Change Page Main Title Locally For a Single Page

Tags: customer, magento2.2, css, login

I want to change the Page.Main.Title styling for my login. I need to apply a css class to the element. But the block, title.phtml is a globally used block and will change all titles.

How can I reference only the login page?

I've tried overwriting the title.phtml in Magento_Customer (in my custom theme), but this applies the changes globally as well.

Comment: are you talking about customer account login page?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya in this case yes. but id like to know how to format the title for a specific page in general

Comment: did you ever get an answer for this? I need to do something similar on just the registration form.